# LibreOffice, GTK3, and Lubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: lubuntu, libreoffice, gtk3

**OS:** Lubuntu 14.04.3 LTS fully updated
**Kernel:** 3.13.0-77-generic

I've just installed `LibreOffice Version: 5.0.4.2, Build ID: 1:5.0.4~rc2-0ubuntu1~trusty1` like this:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/libreoffice-5-0
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

I also installed `libreoffice-gtk3` like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gtk3
```

But LibreOffice is still using gtk2. Are there some other steps I need to take to get LibreOffice to use gtk3? Or is the version of gtk3 I have not sufficient? This is what I see:

```
dpkg -l libgtk2.0-0 libgtk-3-0
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                                 Version                 Architecture            Description
+++-====================================-=======================-=======================-=============================================================================
ii  libgtk-3-0:amd64                     3.10.8-0ubuntu1.6       amd64                   GTK+ graphical user interface library
ii  libgtk2.0-0:amd64                    2.24.23-0ubuntu1.3      amd64                   GTK+ graphical user interface library
```

Comment: With 3.13 kernel it doesn't seem fully updated.

Comment: Do you have a `/etc/profile.d/libreoffice-fresh.sh` file? What does it contain?

Comment: If you close all running instances of LO (say, `pkill soffice`) and run `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk3 soffice` in a terminal, what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a couple of sources, LibreOffice's theme support is controlled by the `SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN` variable (which can be `gtk`, `gtk3`, `qt` and `gen`). You can force usage of GTK3 by:

```
SAL_USE_VCLPLUGIN=gtk3 soffice
```

You might need GTK > 3.10, and apparently there are some show-stopping bugs that are only fixed in GTK 3.18.

References:

1. [Reddit discussion on LO enabling GTK3](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/3o8gky/libreoffice_5023_gui_changes_to_gtk3/)
2. [Arch Wiki article on LO](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LibreOffice#Theme)

Comment: @DKBose updated.

Comment: @DKBose I tried that and saw no difference, so I didn't mention that. (LO 5.0.4.2 and GTK 3.18.4)